# Error in checkError(res) : Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4445: Connection refused

Tags: r, docker

I try to open a remote driver with RSelenium but I keep on facing the same issue with Docker.

Within Docker I run

```
$ docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0
```

then

```
$ docker ps
```

Docker returns

```
CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
a89435c68373 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0 "/opt/bin/entry_poin…" About an hour ago Up About an hour 0.0.0.0:4445->4444/tcp determined_sammet
```

then in R

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L)
remDr$open()
```

and I receive this error

```
Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4445: Connection refused
```

I can't figure out how to handle this. Can anyone help? Thanks

---

Thanks to Ralf Stubner the command

```
 remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "yourIP", port = 4445L)
```

has fixed my issue

Comment: What is the output of the mentioned `docker ps` command?

Comment: CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
a89435c68373        selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0   "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:4445->4444/tcp   determined_sammet

Comment: Thanks. Please [edit] your question to include this additional information. It is really hard to read in a comment.

Comment: Done Ralf. Thanks for your time

Comment: What you describe works for me on Linux. Which OS are you using?

Comment: I use Windows10

Comment: In that case have a look at the `RSelenium::docker` vignette, section "RSelenium and Running Containers". On windows you might have to specify an IP address in addition to the port.

Comment: Thanks Ralf ! remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "myIP", port = 4445L) seems to fix my issue!

Comment: Great. Instead of editing your question you could post this as an answer including how to obtain the IP address.

Answer (score 5):

I've found putting a sleep in between seems to help avoid this error:

```
system("sudo docker pull selenium/standalone-chrome",wait=T)
Sys.sleep(5)
system("sudo docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome",wait=T)
Sys.sleep(5)
remDr <- remoteDriver(port=4445L, browserName="chrome")
Sys.sleep(15)
remDr$open()
```